# html5 / jQuery, Clock that does milliseconds animating every 100ms, <div> or <canvas>?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, performance-testing

I've coded a small stopwatch / clock in jQuery, that will be run on android and iOS using phonegap build, the stopwatch shows the time since the stopwatch was started in the format of "00:00:00.0", it includes milliseconds as the last block of numbers and gets updated every 100ms. I have been looking on google for canvas vs div performance articles but nothing seems to mention how they perform updating text at 100ms intervals.

Im wondering if it would be best to update the text showing the time in a `<div>` or should it be in a `<canvas>` ? At the moment I am using a div and every now and then there is a tiny bit of lag where it looks like the browser cant keep up, any advice / insight into the situation is much appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: You should know that canvas re-draws each cycle, whereas DOM elements are only moved/animated when requested. Even tho I think, with such simple animation, neither would really matter, but that DOM movement (`<div>`) would be faster. The downside to DOM-element animation might be browser performance visually tho. Some browsers tend to make rotating and transforming DOM-elements differently, that said; ugly (sharp edges etc.).

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of canvas being redrawn every cycle, so if the animation lags when using the DOM in theory the timer should still be correct / ontime right?

Comment: The timer won't lag, don't worry. JavaScript engines these days are very high-performance. You won't get hiccups in matter of time, it might just look different with DOM in different browsers. By visual performance I really meant that, not stuttering :) Also what you want to achieve is pretty light. Both would work. I would go for DOM tho, but that's something personal :)

Comment: Ah that's great, thanks heaps! I would be happy to vote this up as an answer if you submitted it as an answer Allendar =]

Comment: I think DOM is the way to go for text-only animations. Have a look here as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2012/01/09/why-is-canvas-so-slow-for-text.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll transcribe the comments here;

> You should know that canvas re-draws each cycle, whereas DOM elements
>   are only moved/animated when requested. Even tho I think, with such
>   simple animation, neither would really matter, but that DOM movement
>   () would be faster.
>
> The downside to DOM-element animation might be browser performance
>   visually tho. Some browsers tend to make rotating and transforming
>   DOM-elements differently, that said; ugly (sharp edges etc.).
>
> The timer won't lag, don't worry. JavaScript engines these days are
>   very high-performance. You won't get hiccups in matter of time, it
>   might just look different with DOM in different browsers. By visual
>   performance I really meant that, not stuttering :)
>
> Also what you want
>   to achieve is pretty light. Both would work. I would go for DOM tho,
>   but that's something personal :)